# Alamofire POST dictionary with row data

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, alamofire

Hi everyone I am currently using Swift 2.2 and Alamofire and I am doing a post/form request using a json. Here is the my current code:

```
func authenticateUserWithValues(passCode : String, userID : String, completion: (result: Bool, user : User?, message : String) -> Void) {

    let urlString = NSString(format:"%@%@", kBaseURL, kCheckAuthenticationCodeURL) as String

    let parameters: [String: String] = [ "code" : passCode,
                                         "user_id": userID,
                                         "application_type" : "2"]


    Alamofire.request(.POST, urlString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { (response) in

            switch response.result {
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
                if (error.code == -1009) {
                    completion(result: false, user: nil, message : kString_No_Internet_Connection)
                }else{
                    completion(result: false, user: nil, message: kString_Unexpected_Error_Occured)
                }
            case .Success(let responseObject):

                let response = responseObject as? [String:String]

                var status : String = ""
                var message : String = ""

                if(response!["status"] != nil){
                    status = response!["status"]!
                }

                if(response!["message"] != nil){
                    message = response!["message"]!
                }

                if (status == "OK"){

                    let user : User = RealmManager().addUser(response!)
                    completion(result: true, user: user, message: message)

                }else{

                    completion(result: false, user: nil, message: message)

                }

                print(responseObject)

            }

    }

}
```

Bu I need to change it to accept a raw body request of the same Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the post request in raw format using Swift 2.2:

```
func authenticateUserWithValues(passCode : String, userID : String, completion: (result: Bool, user : User?, message : String) -> Void) {

    let urlString = NSString(format:"%@%@", kBaseURL, kCheckAuthenticationCodeURL) as String

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData


    let paramString = "{\"code\" : \"\(passCode)\", \"user_id\" : \"\(userID)\", \"application_type\" : \"2\"}"
    request.HTTPBody = paramString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (
        let data, let response, let error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            if (error!.code == -1009) {
                completion(result: false, user: nil, message : kString_No_Internet_Connection)
            }else{
                completion(result: false, user: nil, message: kString_Unexpected_Error_Occured)
            }
            return
        }

        do {

            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]


            var status : String = ""
            var message : String = ""

            if(json["status"] != nil){
                status = json["status"]! as! String
            }

            if(json["message"] != nil){
                message = json["message"]! as! String
            }

            if (status == "OK"){
                RealmManager().removerAllUsers()
                RealmManager().addUser(json)
                let user : User = RealmManager().getCurrentUser()!
                completion(result: true, user: user, message: message)

            }else{

                completion(result: false, user: nil, message: message)

            }


        } catch let error as NSError {
            completion(result: false, user: nil, message: error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    task.resume()

}
```